# Crossing the border 3 times in 24 or 48 hours

Tags: customs-and-immigration, borders, south-africa, lesotho

I am planning on driving up Sani Pass (South Africa - Lesotho) in December 2017. Ideally, I would like to do two trips on two consecutive days. **The concern is, that this would raise red flags and I could be considered an illicit substance courier.** Clearly, nobody wants that type of attention.

On the first trip, I would like to hike on the Lesotho side of the border, and return to South Africa the same day. The next trip would be a one-way trip up the mountain pass, travel through Lesotho to Caledonspoort border crossing, entering South Africa.

I am a South African citizen, with a valid passport, and a 4x4 vehicle. But the question is not about the logistics around this trip. My question is, is this a wise idea to do multiple trips in quick succession?

Comment: A lot of business people do one day trips for many reasons. So you might be searched on arrival, but since you're not bringing drugs, who cares?

Comment: And I would suspect that this kind of trip is par for the course (i.e. quite typical) for the Sani Pass and 4x4 folk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is, is this a wise idea to do multiple trips in quick succession?

Crossing the border 3 times per day is not a big deal, especially when you have a perfectly good explanation. There is no limit to how many times per day you can cross international borders, as long as you aren't violating any other laws.

So relax and enjoy your trip.

Comment: If you're worried, take lots of photos on your trips across the border, which you can show as evidence to the border officer, but I suspect you'll get little to no opposition about it since the explanation is a reasonable one.